# How do you compare between different rock climbing grades?

Tags: rock-climbing, trad-climbing, climbing-grades

Different countries and rock climbing disiplines have different grading systems, for example the the British trad grade system (e.g. grade HVS 5(a))  and the US point grading system (e.g. 5.9)

If I climb HVS 5(a) in the UK, how do I know what this grade equates to in other countries?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Rockfax have a handy conversion chart](http://www.rockfax.com/publications/grades/) this is the generally accepted version though it is (like all climbing grades) subjective.

Below are the conversion charts:

### "Bold" trad routes

[image]

### "Safe" Trad Routes

[image]

### Bouldering

[image]

Comment: Note that the "USA" columns would be better labeled "YDS" ([Yosemite Decimal System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosemite_Decimal_System)).

Comment: Funny that the British apparently rate climbs "difficult" or "very difficult" that you can essentially *walk* up with your hands tied behind your back... :)

Comment: Bare in mind the British adjective system dates back to the early 20th century and the style of ascent must be on-sight and use traditional protection. which at the time would have meant soloing in hob nail boots.